# How many bits to flip in an RSA public key to do signature forgery?

Tags: rsa, signature, forgery

Scenario: Alice wants to verify a signature from Bob. Alice knows Bob's RSA public key (e, n). However, Alice is getting the data, the signature of the data and the public key from an attacker Eve. Assume the signature is compliant with PKCS# v1.5.

Now I know trivially Eve can generate an RSA key pair and signs the data herself and send the fake public key and fake signature to Alice. But I am going put a constraint on Eve. Eve cannot generate whatever key pairs she likes. Even has to flip the (e, n).

My question: What is the least number of bits she needs to flip in (e, n) such that she can forge the signature?

NOTE: she can either generate a signature from Bob's private key or she can generate a signature from some other private key she can compute from the corrupted public key or whatever attack she can come up with. As long as she can convince Alice the signature is from Bob.

Comment: What do you mean by: "Even has to flip the (e, n)."?

Comment: Do you mean: Eve is restricted to invent (e', n') that differ from (e, n) in a small number of bits ? If yes, what is the convention used to map (e, n) to a bitstring ? In particular, would it prevent changing the customary e=65537 to e=1 by flipping the high-order bit, or would that be otherwise rejected by Alice ?

Comment: @otus, flipping bits in the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Eve can find an $n'$ that is prime (and $n'-1$ is relatively prime to $e$),then she can easily sign any message with that $n', e$ pair.

So, the question is: what is the probability that there exists a prime $n'$ such that there is only one bit difference between $n$ and $n'$, and $n' \not\equiv 1 \pmod {e}$ ?  The answer is that it is quite good if $e > 3$, and decent even if $e = 3$. We'll assume $e$ is prime; in practice, it almost always is.

There are $log_2 n$ integers that have one bit difference from $n$ (we'll assume that Eve cannot flip bits that increase the size of $n$); flipping bit 0 will obviously yield a composite; flipping any other bit will yield an odd integer.  A "random" odd integer of size circa $n$ has a circa $2/{\log_e n}$ probability of prime; if we model each of the odd integers as "random", then we would expect around $(\log_2 n - 1) 2/{\log_e n} \approx. 2.89$ primes to be about one bit flip away from $n$; alternatively, there would a probability approximately $(1 - 2/{\log_e n}) ^ {\log_2 n - 1} \approx. 0.044$ that none of the values 1 bit away from $n$ happen to be prime.  When we include the condition with $e$, we know $n$ always satisifies the condition, and so a value with a bit flipped would have probability $1/(e-1)$ of satisfying it; from that, we can see that with $e=3$, we have an expected $1.44$ values satisfying it (hence we have a better than average chance); for $e>3$, the probability is even higher.

And, once we consider $n'$ values that aren't prime, but are easily factored (they're a large prime times a smooth number), the probability becomes much higher)

Comment: Nice. Flipping a single bit of $e$ to make it $1$, if $e$ is suitable (most $e$ used in practice are), and that's accepted by Alice (which would not be unseen), is another way, involving less work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A "random" odd integer of size circa n has a circa $2/log_{e}n$ probability of prime. I assume this $e$ is not the public exponent and is the natural logarithm constant, correct? Is it possible to point me to a reference of this claim?

Comment: "alternatively, there would a probability approximately...", I think the number after this sentence is multiplication rather than exponentiation.

Comment: @dannycrane: Yes, in $2/{\log_e n}$ the letter $e$ is the base of natural logarithm, not the public exponent. $\;$ No, in $(1 - 2/{\log_e n}) ^ {\log_2 n - 1} \approx 0.044$, exponentiation is meant; think of $\log_2 n - 1$ as a number of trials, each flipping a bit with odds $1-2/{\log_e n}$ of _not_ reaching a prime.

Comment: ... but I presume you could detect a forgery if you were suspicious, as setting $d$ to such a low value would make the "private key" easy to factor.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: actually, it wouldn't set $d$ to a low value; instead, it would be detectable because the proported $n$ would be prime (alternatively, easy to factor), should anyone happen to check.

Comment: I did not completely follow the paragraph "When we include the condition with e, ..., the probability is even higher." After you compute the probability of prime after the modulus n is flipped, do you need to compute the probability that gcd(e, n-1) = 1? I dont see how this probability is linked to your calculation 1/(e-1).

Comment: @dannycrane: what I was thinking was that we knew that $n' \bmod e \ne 0$ (because we previously checked that $n'$ was prime), and hence there are $e-1$ possible values of $n' \bmod e$, one of which is 1.  Actually, if we look deeper, it's rather more complex.  Actually, if $e=3$, and $n$ is a standard RSA modulus (with two prime factors), the probability that $n' \bmod e \ne 1$ is 1; that's because $n \bmod e = 1$ (as it's the product of two $2 \bmod 3$ primes), and $n-n' \bmod e \ne 0$ (as that difference is $2^k$, for some integer $k$)

Comment: @poncho, could you explain why $n$ mod $e$ = 1 is the case when we use standard RSA modulus? also why ($n$ - $n^{'}$) mod $e$ $\neq$ 0?

Comment: @dannycrane: that was discussing the $e=3$ case; if $n = pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes, then $p=2 \pmod{3}$ (because that's a requirement that RSA makes if $e=3$) and $q = 2 \pmod{3}$ (ditto), and hence $pq = 2\cdot 2 = 1 \pmod{3}$.  As for what $n - n'$ is nonzero mod $e$, well, flipping bit $k$ of $n$ will either increase it's value by $2^k$ (if the bit was original 0), or decrease it by $2^k$ (if it was 1).  Hence, $n - n'$ is either $2^k$ or $-2^k$.  As $e$ is odd, then neither $2^k$ nor $-2^k$ will be a multiple of $e$, and that's what $(n - n') \bmod e \ne 0$ means

Comment: @poncho, thank you for the explanation. I am sorry that I failed to see how you get 1.44. Without knowing the value of $e$, how did you get this concrete result?

Comment: @dannycrane: In that clause, I was assuming that the public exponent $e=3$.  A simple calculation (and substituting in the value of $e$) gives $2.89 \times 1/(3-1) \approx 1.44$